# find all factor pairs from array in php

Tags: php, optimization

Consider an array (2,3,4,5)

I need to make possible combinations like

`(2,60),(6,20),(24,5),(10,12),(30,4) (8,15)`= factor pair for 120

One solutions is using `for loop`. One running from `0` to `currentPos` and other from `currentPos` to `N` (where N is count of factor array i.e 4 in this case)

```
for($i=$pos;$i>=0;$i--)
{
  $p1 = $p1 * $factorArr[$i];
}
for($j=$pos;$j<=$N;$j++)
{
  $p2 = $p2 * $factorArr[$j];
}
```

where as $pos is increase

Anyone who knows a better way to do this in PHP?

Comment: What is the relevance of the initial array? How is it related?

Comment: If you just want to check the pairs for the values in the array: [https://eval.in/612448](https://eval.in/612448)

Comment: I just don't understand why you have `10,12` and `6,20`.. maybe you want to be able to multiply by themselves too? (If so, why not `8,15`?)

Comment: Maybe this gets closer to what you want: [https://eval.in/612452](https://eval.in/612452)

Comment: will you make you idea clear.

Comment: This would be much better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @FirstOne Yes(8,15) I missed it will be one more pair. I have to create all possible pairs.

Comment: @L.feir Consider a scenario if you have a array and you have to create all possible pairs (one pair have two element) . In my case I have factors and then I am trying to create pairs. I did for using two loops and didn't like my own code. Looking for some other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will get all combinations without repetition:

```
$factor = 5;
$arr = range(1, $factor); // (1,2,3,4,5)
$f = array_product($arr);
$pairs = array();
$unique = array();
for($i = 1; $i < $f/2; $i++){ // only need to check until half (the other half would repeat the values
    // if not divisable / already found
    if($f % $i != 0 || isset($unique[$i]) || isset($unique[$f/$i])){
        continue;
    }
    $pairs[] = array( $i, $f/$i );
    $unique[$i] = true;
}
```

The result (`$pairs`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 120
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 60
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 40
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 30
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 24
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 20
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 15
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 12
        )

)
```

See it in action [here](https://eval.in/612710).

---

If you need it like in the question, you can use this code:

```
$p = array();
foreach($pairs as $pair){
    $p[] = sprintf('(%s,%s)', $pair[0], $pair[1]);
}
```

Result (`$p`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => (1,120)
    [1] => (2,60)
    [2] => (3,40)
    [3] => (4,30)
    [4] => (5,24)
    [5] => (6,20)
    [6] => (8,15)
    [7] => (10,12)
)
```

**Sidenote:** you can do this in the first code - no need to created another loop just for this (after `$pairs[] = array( $i, $f/$i );`, you could use `$p[] = sprintf('(%s,%s)', $i, $f/$i);`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop.  If you already have all the factors then all you need is a foreach loop on your array.  Here's an example that outputs the pairs, but you can assign the value from the division operation to another variable or to another array, etc.  If you need to discover the factors, it's only slightly different but is a different question.

```
$number = 120;
$factors = [1,2,3,4,5,8,10];

foreach($factors as $factor){
    echo "($factor," . $number/$factor . ")\n</br>";
}
```

Comment: If not wrong 1,2,3,4,5 are the prime factors. So I won't be having 8 and 10 in that array

Comment: That's fine - it's just an example set of factors.  If I understand correctly, you already have the factors, so just put the ones you want into the array and leave the ones you don't want out.